# Compiling WebKit for Windows8-Metro Environment

Tags: compilation, webkit, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I would like to ask the SO community for the following information:
- Is it possible to compile WebKit for Windows8-Metro Environment, either in the form of a WinRT component or just as a linked library in a C++/XAML application?
- Which are the main steps to achieve this goal?
- Which are the possible things that would make this not possible or very difficult?
- Is it an endeavour someone is working on just now?
- Is it possible to gather interested people so they work on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will not be able to just "compile" Webkit for WinRT/Metro Style. Metro Style applications are restricted in the kind of API calls they can make, for example there is no GDI/GDI+/MFC for WinRT. WebKit has several building modes that you can use, you can either build it using QT as rendering engine, or using GTK, or plain GDI, but on all those cases, when you create new builds for Windows OSes you will be using GDI at the very end.

Nevertheless, you could modify Webkit source code and add a new rendering engine that uses WinRT new APIs. You could probably become famous if you do.

As a side note, even when there is a "Windows Store" version of Chrome, by looking at the source code of Chromium it seems to me that this version is just a simple app launcher that communicates with the "normal" desktop version using an IPC channel. It does not appear to be a real Windows Store build of the whole source code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the WinRT environment will allow this, but there is a project called [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/) that is a wrapper around Google Chrome and Google Chrome is based on WebKit I think. It also has a .NET wrapper, so you can embedd it onto your .NET app.

I never tried using it, neither I know about if this library is applicable with WinRT, but at least it is a start.

- [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/)
- [Awesomium .NET samples](http://awesomium.codeplex.com)
- [DownMakerWPF](https://github.com/Code52/DownmarkerWPF), an application embedding it to display markdown.

Answer (score 0):

WinRT is a combination of managed and native code, so, you have a chance to port WebKit, but remember - native code have some sandbox restrictions.

Also you can choose XNA instead.

Comment: Please can you say more? I am interested in customizing webKit and compiling it.

Comment: First, you must have access to WebKit source code. I recommend it instead VP8, because it faster and free without google.
Second, you must understand WebKit architecture, which based on native code. 
Third, you must remade architecture for managed .NET code with .NET advantages. 
Fourth - port to .NET.
Fifth, catch bugs and run after standarts. 

Your biggest problem is not html, but css and js will stop you. 
One human can spend whole life for porting big old project to new architecture, you must have a powerful .NET team.

Comment: Are you saying that WinRT is not enough low-level to allow porting WebKit at native code level?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying.
You must ready to reinvent native code architecture, which uses a lot of hacks.

Comment: But browser on managed code isn't a myth - you can see Opera Mini, which run on J2ME without lags (that strange for java apps, lol). .NET Framework faster, and you have a good chances.

Comment: I am sorry but I still think you can always create a WinRT module (that is, showing itself as managed code assembly to Metro apps) compiling it from a native code C++ base. So WinRT doesn't prevent low-level native code from executing and showing itself like a WinRT module (.NET managed style).

Comment: You can use C++/X instead, but I think, you need modify code.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. WinRT is a combination of managed and native code, so, you have a chance to port WebKit, but remember - native code have some sandbox restrictions.

Comment: XNA is not supported in Windows 8 Store Apps.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. You can use DirectX instead.